# How to handle access violation?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, ihtmldocument2

Certain functions in my program get a bad pointer with a low probability.

The pointer is the `CComPtr <IHTMLDocument2> m_htmldocument2` variable.

Moving the `m_htmldocument2` variable to a local variable causes an access violation error if `m_htmldocument2` is not a valid value.

I did not have a way to check if `m_htmldocument2` was a valid value, and tried to process it as __try __except, but I could not do it because there was a destructor.

Is there a safe way to move to a local variables?

Comment: `CComPtr <IHTMLDocument2> m_htmldocument2` is only a declaration, declaring it on stack will not cause random errors. COM has plenty of error checking. It's not known what you are doing that's causing an error.